# How to delete a letter before last letter in textDocumentProxy in iOS?

Tags: nsstring, ios8, textdocumentproxy

We can use `deleteBackward` in `TextDocumentProxy` to delete a last letter.

Now i need to delete a letter of last letter.

Eg. `Apple` , i want to delete `l` letter before `e`.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Get the last character from the `documentContextBeforeInput`, delete twice, and add the character as text.

If you feel this API is lacking, make sure to open a bug report and/or an enhancement report with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I did... Its not perfect but good for a now to delete last word. You might found it useful.

```
-(void) removeLastWordFromInput{
    for (int i = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput.length - 1;i > 0; i--) {
        if ([self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput characterAtIndex:i] == ' ')
            return;

        //delete last character
        [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
    }
}
```